# What should I do with these mushrooms in my yard?

Tags: mushrooms

I have some mushrooms showing up around my landscape. Do I just remove them like any other weed or do I need to do anything special?

[image]

Comment: Wood chips = rotting wood = mushrooms.

Comment: why do you consider them weeds?

Comment: @Nic that is the question I am asking (indirectly).  Do I leave them, remove them or something else and why

Comment: A weed being "a plant out of place" I have to wonder if it's possible for a fungus, which is not a plant, to be a weed?

Comment: This question is opinon based, whether folks answering are mycophilic ( Mushrooms are a good sign usually – Escoce ) or mycophobic ( remove them as you can't tell if they're edible or poisonous, and a pet might eat them. – Graham Chiu )

Comment: I love having mushrooms pop up.  I think they are charming.

Answer (score 6):

If you take the fruiting body (mushroom) off, you'll leave behind the [mycelium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mycelium) ("roots") which are busily turning your wood mulch into finer mulch. Ask yourself if you have a moisture problem in that area, and if so, attempt to fix it. If it's been raining a lot, just pull the mushroom and keep an eye on the area for a few weeks. You may just have a transient problem.

Comment: If the roots are decomposing the wood mulch, I would say that is a good thing vs. a "problem".  Please clarify.

Comment: Those chips look like the dyed type that are used instead of ground cover in parts of the US. Having it decay will lead to soil and then unwanted plants.

Comment: Mushrooms are a good sign usually

Comment: @escoce please elaborate on what you mean?  Are you suggesting I leave the mushrooms as is i.e. let them grow and they won't harm anything but to the contrary are beneficial?

Comment: Remove them as you can't tell if they're edible or poisonous, and a pet might eat them.