# What kind of mushroom is this and should I get rid of it?

Tags: vegetables, soil, mushrooms, rain

We got a lot of rain in Austin over the last few days and now there are mushrooms popping up all over my vegetable garden. The garden bed is raised and only about two weeks old. I'm worried the mushrooms are growing too fast and too close to the plants.

Does anyone know what they are, and if I should try to get rid of them?

Here's a picture:

[image: Mushrooms]

Comment: Potential duplicate to http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/23643/mushrooms-what-to-do

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks like typical wooden-linked mushroom. They come here to feed on the wood you put to feed your earth and this is a good thing: It shows that life is working around your plants in your garden. They won't be a problem to your young plants because they feed on something different, and even better, they enrich the soil for them!

The mushrooms will disappear as soon as soil isn't moist enough for them.

They aren't dangerous mushroom, so you have nothing to do, just let them do their work.